# "В какой-то мере (степени)" с глаголами

Tags: семантика

Возможно ли употребление "в какой-то мере (степени)" с глаголами, в значении ограничения действия, выраженного ими?

Я тоже так думал в какой-то мере.
Мне кажется в какой-то степени.
Резать продукты при готовке в какой-то мере - неэффективно. Следует их резать уверенно, твердо.

Если нет, то как выразить частичное совпадение мнений?

Я в какой-то степени согласен с тобой? 
Я думаю сходным образом?

Answer (score 1):

Употребление данных словосочетаний с глаголами абсолютно естественно для русского языка. Более того, они чаще всего и относятся именно к глаголу — прямо или косвенно.

Но употреблять данные словосочетания нужно **перед** глаголом:
*В зависимости от личности партнера **в какой-то мере меняется** и характер аргументации.*
*Ну, а если серьезно, то это **в какой-то мере отражает** нашу беззаботность.*

*Каждый ребенок в какой-то мере гений, и каждый гений в какой-то мере ребенок (Артур Шопенгауэр).* || Даже при существительном словосочетание косвенно относится к пропущенному глаголу "являться" — в какой-то мере является гением.

Более литературный вариант — в некоторой степени.

Comment: То есть "В некоторой степени я тоже так думаю" допустимо? А если все-таки в постпозиции?

Comment: С "думаю" оно плохо сочетается. Или думаю, или нет. Получается, что "тоже так чуть-чуть думаю" - как-то странно звучит. А вот с "кажется" уже хорошо. В постпозиции оно будет относится к слову после глагола.

Comment: А если этот оборот - заключительный в предложении?

Comment: Это неестественный порядок слов (для него нет причин), но грамматически допустимо.